# integrating js code inside react component

Tags: reactjs

I have converted a component that displays chart bar, and it requires this js snippet to run, what is the correct way of integrating it inside my JSX code?

```
<script>
    /** START JS Init "Peity" Bar (Sidebars/With Avatar & Stats) from sidebar-avatar-stats.html **/
    $(".bar.peity-bar-primary-avatar-stats").peity("bar", {
        fill: ["#2D99DC"],
        width: 130,
    })
</script>
```

I have seen this libraries on npm website, but they mostly deal with external scripts not internal

here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
          "How can I render js code here?" 
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) callback in order to initialize jquery plugins, like so

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    $(this.barChart).peity("bar", { 
      fill: ["#2D99DC"], width: 130
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      <div ref={ (node) => { this.barChart = node }  }>
        <span class="bar">5,3,9,6,5,9,7,3,5,2</span>
        <span class="bar">5,3,2,-1,-3,-2,2,3,5,2</span>
        <span class="bar">0,-3,-6,-4,-5,-4,-7,-3,-5,-2</span>
      </div>  
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peity/3.2.1/jquery.peity.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) [lifecycle hook](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class).
Add this to your component code:

```
componentDidMount() {
 $(".bar.peity-bar-primary-avatar-stats").peity("bar", {
        fill: ["#2D99DC"],
        width: 130,
    })
}
```